# Chisel3. Functional Module Mux4

Tags: scala, module, riscv, mux, chisel

I'm learning Chisel following the documentation [on Github](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel3/wiki/Short%20Users%20Guide%20to%20Chisel)

Thus far, everything worked flawlessly. But i'm stuck at chapter 13,  ["Functional Module Creation"](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel3/wiki/Functional%20Module%20Creation)

I **can't get the code to work**. I created all my .scala classes in a copy of the chisel-template-project. Here is what i wrote / copied to create a **Mux4 with variable bit width**:

/chisel-template/src/main/scala/**Mux4.scala**

```
import Chisel._

class Mux4(w: Int) extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
        val sel = UInt(INPUT, 2)
        val in0 = UInt(INPUT, w)
        val in1 = UInt(INPUT, w)
        val in2 = UInt(INPUT, w)
        val in3 = UInt(INPUT, w)
        val out = UInt(OUTPUT, w)
  })

  io.out := Mux2(io.sel(1), 
                    Mux2(io.sel(0), io.in0, io.in1),
                    Mux2(io.sel(0), io.in2, io.in3))
}


class Mux2(w: Int) extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
        val sel = Bool(INPUT)
        val in0 = UInt(INPUT, w)
        val in1 = UInt(INPUT, w)
        val out = UInt(OUTPUT, w)
  })

  when(io.sel) {
    io.out := io.in0
  }.otherwise {
    io.out := io.in1
  }
}


object Mux2 {
  def apply(sel: UInt, in0: UInt, in1: UInt): UInt = {
    val m = new Mux2(in0.getWidth) 
    m.io.sel := sel.toBool()
    m.io.in0 := in0
    m.io.in1 := in1
    m.io.out
  }
}
```

The Tester scala class i wrote:

/chisel-template/src/test/scala/**Mux4Test.scala**

```
import Chisel.iotesters.{ChiselFlatSpec, Driver, PeekPokeTester}

class Mux4Test(c: Mux4) extends PeekPokeTester(c) {

      val sel = 3
      val (in0, in1, in2, in3) = (5, 7, 11, 15)

      poke(c.io.sel, sel)
      poke(c.io.in0, in0)
      poke(c.io.in1, in1)
      poke(c.io.in2, in2)
      poke(c.io.in3, in3)
      step(1)
      System.out.println("Circuit: "+peek(c.io.out)
          +"  Expected: "+TestMux4.result(sel, in0, in1, in2, in3))
}

object TestMux4{
  def result(sel: Int, in0: Int, in1: Int, in2: Int, in3: Int): Int = {
    val out = sel match{
      case 0 => in3
      case 1 => in2
      case 2 => in1
      case 3 => in0
    }
    out
  }
}

class Mux4Tester extends ChiselFlatSpec {
  behavior of "Mux4"
  backends foreach {backend =>
    it should s"do Mux4 $backend" in {
      Driver(() => new Mux4(4), backend)(c => new Mux4Test(c)) should be (true)
    }
  }
}
```

The important part from the **output**

```
STEP 0 -> 1
Circuit: 0  Expected: 5
```

The Mux4 class (Circuit) returns 0 as output, whereas it should be 5, because the selection process is as follows:

00 -> io.out = in3 = 15

01 -> io.out = in2 = 11

10 -> io.out = in1 = 7

11 -> io.out = in0 = 5

In the Mux4Test.scala class i wrote **val sel = 3**. The bit representation of this is **11** and therefore i'd expect **in0 = 5**.

Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for your interest in Chisel!

I ran your example, and after scratching my head for a while I found the problem: when you instantiate a Chisel Module, you need to make sure to wrap it in `Module(...)` (EDIT: The code on the wiki omitted this wrapper. This has been fixed). Thus, object Mux2 should instead be:

```
object Mux2 {
  def apply(sel: UInt, in0: UInt, in1: UInt): UInt = {
    val m = Module(new Mux2(in0.getWidth)) // <- See Here
    m.io.sel := sel.toBool()
    m.io.in0 := in0
    m.io.in1 := in1
    m.io.out
  }
}
```

With this change, it looks like the code works!

Comment: I also just realized that the example on the actual wiki has the same bug. My apologies! I'll fix it right away.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer @jkoenig. Now it works !

Comment: I have also PRed a fix to ensure that this error is caught in the future, sorry about any frustration this has caused!

Answer (score 0):

didn't read all your code, but I think the Mux2 arguments are in the wrong order here:

Mux2(io.sel(0), io.in0, io.in1)