# Chisel3: How to get verilog,cpp and vcd files simultaneously

Tags: scala, build, chisel

I am a novice with chisel. I would be using it in my project in coming days and I am trying to get familiar with the library.

After working with [Chisel-tutorials](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-tutorial) I have got a better hang of how things work in chisel. In tutorials, everything has been provided organized in a manner to make things easier for beginners (I suppose that is the purpose of tutorials!).

Now, i want to move onto next part, where i would like to develop my own small projects and dive a bit more into how chisel works (generating verilog, cpp, vcd) from say a simple `Mux4.scala` file in chisel. (I am taking the correct version of Mux4 module code and tester from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40532039/chisel3-functional-module-mux4?rq=1)).
I just added the following lines at the end of `Mux4.scala`

```
object Mux4Driver extends App {
  chisel3.Driver.execute(args, () => new Mux4(32))
}
```

to get the verilog code directly.

I have placed the scala file in `src/main/scala/` and tester in `src/test/scala/`.

Here is where I am having trouble. As pointed out by jkoenig, I can run my code by using the command `sbt "run-main Mux4Driver"` in the root directory. On doing so i get three files,`Mux4.fir`,`Mux4.v`, `Mux4.anno`.

1. But how can I get various files(screenshot below) which i got by using

   `TESTER_BACKENDS=verilator ./run-examples.sh GCD`

when i am implementing my own module.(I understand that i can pass the verilog file through verilator to get cpp files, but is there any sleek way to get all the files at once like in tutorials [There should be a way, but i just could not figure it out])
 [image]

(I am using the [chisel-template](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-template) for my project).

2. I understand that after writing modules, it seems like knowledge of sbt is required to successfully run your code and generate the required files. I would like to understand how I can use sbt to organize my projects like in chisel tutorials and run them with a single command (like `./run-examples.sh mymodule`).

I have done research on my end for above questions but could not get clarity. I would appreciate if you can compile a few steps for new users like me on how to deal with your own projects.

**Edit**:

On trying out the commands mentioned in the answer below I got the following errors:

[image]

And on trying out `--help` my options are different from what you have suggested. On matching my `--help` output with the output [here](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel3-wiki/blob/master/Running-Stuff.md) i find that i don't have tester options in my output.

[image]

Is this some issue with the version of Chisel (using Chisel3) or sbt I am using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This is amended for the changes to the question*.

The [chisel-template repo](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-template) is a reasonable example of how to organize your further development efforts.  But based on your question, I would recommend you use a one of two different method of invoking your unit tests.

```
class GCDTester extends ChiselFlatSpec {
  "GCD" should "calculate proper greatest common denominator" in {
    iotesters.Driver.execute(Array(), () => new GCD) {
      c => new GCDUnitTester(c)
    } should be (true)
  }
}
```

or

```
object GCDMain extends App {
  iotesters.Driver.execute(args, () => new GCD) {
    c => new GCDUnitTester(c)
  }
}
```

One **important** difference from your code in your question is that the Driver referenced above is `chisel3.iotesters.Driver` instead of `chisel3.Driver`. 
You can use command line arguments with either, for example:
Add --help to the arguments like

```
iotesters.Driver.execute(Array("--help"), () => new GCD) {
```

and run your test, or run the *main* from the second example:

```
sbt 'runMain examples.GCDMain --help'
```

Either way, you will see the large number of available options.
You are interested in

```
  -tbn, --backend-name <firrtl|verilator|vcs>
                           backend to use with tester, default is firrtl
```

and maybe

```
  -fiwv, --fint-write-vcd  writes vcd execution log, filename will be base on top
```

You can add any of these arguments, in the same way you --help was added. So to run verilator

```
iotesters.Driver.execute(Array("--backend-name", "verilator"), () => new GCD) {
```

and run your test, or run the *main* from the second example:

```
sbt 'runMain examples.GCDMain --backend-name verilator'
```

The chisel.Driver only supports a subset of the options of the iotesters.Driver and does not include verilator.

Getting all the files you want requires that you run a simulation on your circuit which require some sort of test harness.  The `iotesters.Driver.execute` will invoke your test harness, which will create the files you are interested in (when run with `--backend-name verilator`).  The chisel.Driver.execute only elaborates the circuit, it does not run a simulation.

Note:Although the --fint-write-vcd is only for getting a VCD output file when using the interpreter, I believe using the verilator backend output vcd by default.

Comment: oooh, I have seen these command line options before but could not relate to them here.  I will try them out. Any comments on how to organize projects like chisel-tutorials (using something like run-example.sh) or is it not clear what I am asking(I also feel so)?

Comment: I don't think there is a single answer.  For the most part single module tests are typically run from a test harness.  And as you start composing modules into more complex circuits most people start creating scripts that manage their particular flow.  It depends a lot on the environment you are targeting.

Comment: I have edited the question after running the above commands (could not include the output in comments. Apologies if this is not the way to do it). Please have a look